# Go to line python

Tags: python, goto

I want my program to go to a certain line in the program which is running when it I needed to and run from there.  Is this possible and if so How can this be done?

Comment: gotos are a terrible idea. Use modules, functions and objects

Answer (score 3):

Put whatever lines you want to be done in a function, then put the function call where you want.  `Goto` is bad form in any language, and **it doesn't exist in Python**.

If you think your code is too short to warrant a full function, you can use a `lambda` function (but those can be tricky).

Comment: I want it to loop back to that line and run the next section from there

Comment: @dashernasher So take that section and put it in a function.  You can do whatever it is you want to do without a `goto` command, you just have to structure your script the right way

Comment: There is no case whatsoever when someone would replace a goto with a lambda. Your second paragraph is... weird.